# Url returns 404 not found in Angular 12 web version

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

this is the first time i created a website with Angular. I uploaded the website on the server and it works ok. I browse around it and the pages show ok but if I copy a url from the website e.g. [www.project.com/app/home/users/22](http://www.project.com/app/home/users/22), paste it and hit enter i am getting a 404 not found. If i try to navigate to user 22 link from the initial link e.g. [www.project.com/](http://www.project.com/) it goes just fine and shows the page. Why i am getting a 404 page and how can i fix it?

Thanks

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from "./guards/auth.guard";
import { GuestPageModule } from "./pages/guest/guest.module";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
//  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomePageModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/welcome/welcome.module').then(m => m.WelcomePageModule) 
  }, 
  {path: 'app', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tablinks/tablinks.module').then(m => m.TablinksPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'guest',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/guest/guest.module').then(m => m.GuestPageModule)
      },
      { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserPageModule) },
  ]
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule) 
  },
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/register/register.module').then(m => m.RegisterPageModule) },
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule) },
  { path: 'terms', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/terms/terms.module').then(m => m.TermsPageModule) },
  { path: 'eula', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/eula/eula.module').then(m => m.EULAPageModule)},
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule) },
  { path: 'privacy', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/privacy/privacy.module').then(m => m.PrivacyPageModule)},
  { path: 'forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.ForgotPasswordPageModule) },
  {
    path: 'notifications-setings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/notifications-setings/notifications-setings.module').then( m => m.NotificationsSetingsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'media-ad-details',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/mediaPromote/media-ad-details/media-ad-details.module').then( m => m.MediaAdDetailsPageModule)
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and the url i am trying to reach is https://www.project.com/guest/user/651

link to that

```
<a (click)="goUser(user)" >


 goUser(user: any) {
    user = user;
    this.userData.userViewed(user).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        if (data.success) {
          const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
              user: user
            }
          };
          this.router.navigate(['guest/user' + id], navigationExtras);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }
```

and the guest-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { GuestPage } from './guest.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: GuestPage,
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('../user/user.module').then( m => m.UserPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'creativeSettings',
    loadChildren: () => import('../creative-settings/creative-settings.module').then( m => m.CreativeSettingsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notifications',
    loadChildren: () => import('../notifications-setings/notifications-setings.module').then( m => m.NotificationsSetingsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'believers',
    loadChildren: () => import('../user-believers/user-believers.module').then( m => m.UserBelieversPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'media/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('../media/media.module').then( m => m.MediaPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'flows',
    loadChildren: () => import('../user-flows/user-flows.module').then( m => m.UserFlowsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'appearance',
    loadChildren: () => import('../user-flows/user-flows.module').then( m => m.UserFlowsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    loadChildren: () => import('../about/about.module').then( m => m.AboutModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'terms',
    loadChildren: () => import('../terms/terms.module').then( m => m.TermsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'privacy',
    loadChildren: () => import('../privacy/privacy.module').then( m => m.PrivacyPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'eula',
    loadChildren: () => import('../eula/eula.module').then( m => m.EULAPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class GuestPageRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: what are your Router configurations?

Comment: Where can i see that Najam?

Comment: in your `app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: i updated to show you.

Comment: it goes there just fine but if i hit refresh i am getting the 404 error not found. it seems it looses connection

Comment: It's not about loosing connection. You need to configure the server to treat it as a single page app. Those are angular routes not node routes.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I think that i have to change my .htaccess file?

Comment: In which server are you hosting the app?

Comment: yes you have to update .htaccess for angular apps.

Comment: i did i put FallbackResource /index.html and now it doesnt give a 404 but gives a blank page and an error The resource from “https://project.com/guest/media/capacitor.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)  how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the lazy loading of the guest module is malformed.

```json
  {
    path: 'guest',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/guest/guest.module').then(m => m.GuestPageModule)
  }
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#create-a-feature-module-with-routing

This also seems weird, there should be a slash `/` before `id` - but maybe you have the slash in the id variable.

```
this.router.navigate(['guest/user' + id], navigationExtras);
```